# ООП, Классы, Пакеты

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Подскажите по коду правильно ли составлена задача по стилю используя ООП, Классы, Пакеты!

Просто нужно использовать пример задачи в стиле ООП, Классы, Пакеты!

Или можно правильный пример реализации кода!

Задача: нахождение площади квадрата!

1) пакет squarearea.main

```
package squarearea.main;
import squarearea.peremen.Peremen;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       Peremen per = new Peremen();
       per.usl(2, 1);
   }
}
```

2) пакет squarearea.peremen

```
package squarearea.peremen;
/**
* Класс для объявления площади и значения
*/
public class Peremen {
   private int value;
   private int square;

   Peremen() {
   }

   Peremen(int value, int square) {
       this.value = value;
       this.square = square;
   }

   public int getValue() {
       return value;
   }

   public int getSquare() {
       return square;
   }

   public void setValue(int value) {
       this.value = value;
   }

   public void setSquare(int square) {
       this.square = square;
  }
}
```

3) пакет squarearea.uslovie

```
package squarearea.uslovie;
import squarearea.peremen.Peremen;
/**
* Класс для нахождения площади квадрата
*/

public class Uslovie {
  public void usl(Peremen value, Peremen square){
     square = value.getValue() * value.getValue();
     System.out.println("Значение = " + square);
   }
```

или такой вариант записи не знаю какой правильный

```
  public void usl(int value, int square){
     square = value * value;
       System.out.println("Значение = " + square);
   } 
}
```

Comment: что за новый стиль "ООП, Классы, Пакеты!", я что то пропустил?

Comment: Нет просто хотел оформить код используя разные пакеты и чтоб они были взаимосвязаны с классами!

Comment: второй вариант верный, метод, производящий операцию, не должен зависеть от другого класса, его задача умножать int. Вы создаете экземпляр класса Peremen и вызываете метод класса Uslovie, как так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у тебя маленькая задача что бы заморачиватся с класами и пакетами, они все бы хорошо лежали в одном, другое дело если бы у тебя мыли классы не только для квадрата, а и для других фигур или еще какаето логика